# Concatenate row with it's following ones when each row is a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following DataFrame

```
dict_test = {'a':[['1','2'], ['t','rba'], ['5','6','20'],['7','9'],['sar']],'b':['John','John','John','Tom','Tom']}


df = pd.DataFrame(dict_test)
```

[image]

I've been searching for a way to reshape it in a way such that I end up with

```
dict_test2 = {'a':[['1','2'], ['1','2','t','rba'], ['1','2','t','rba','5','6','20'],['7','9'],['7','9','sar']],'b':['John','John','John','Tom','Tom']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_test2)
```

[image]

Unluckily, I'm not familiar enough with pandas to come up with such a transformation. If anyone has one, or a tip, I will highly appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp = {}

def adder(row):
    if row['b'] not in temp.keys():
           temp[row['b']]=row['a']
           return row['a']
    else:
           new_var=row['a']+temp[row['b']]
           temp[row['b']] = new_var
           return new_var

for index,row in df.iterrows():
       df.at[index,'a'] = adder(row)
```

Explanantion: Iter through every row of your dataframe. Take a temp dictionary. in adder(), if the name in column 'b' is coming for 1st time, set up key for that name in temp dict & return row['a'] else add value from temp for the name in column 'b' alongside row['a'] value for that row. Do setup temp[row['b]] with new updated value

Comment: Very clear and concise, I like it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

you can also do

```
df['a']=df.groupby('b')['a'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
print(df)
```

results:

```
0                    [1, 2]  John
1            [1, 2, t, rba]  John
2  [1, 2, t, rba, 5, 6, 20]  John
3                    [7, 9]   Tom
4               [7, 9, sar]   Tom
```